# kotlin - class grouping like sealed class

Tags: kotlin

client can request to server like this (only 3 types of values are available and length could be larger than 3)

```
{
  data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "string"
  },
{
    "id": 2,
  "value": {
    "address" : "1",
    "next" : "3",
  }
  },
{
    "id": 3,
  "value": {
    "count" : "1",
    "option" : "3",
  }
  },
```

and I want to group 3 kinds of value types
string / { "count", "option"} / {"address", "next"}

```
data class Request(
  val data: SealedLikeClass,
)
```

how can I define `SealedLikeClass` ?
I don't know how to include string in sealed class

Comment: Are you trying to serialise or deserialise this JSON? Or both?

Comment: both !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a sealed class hierarchy with a generic `Request<T>`. This will restrict the `T` type-parameter to be exactly of the 3 forms you mentioned. You could remove this restriction by removing the `sealed`-keyword.

Like this:

```kotlin
sealed interface Request<T> {
    val id: Int
    val value: T
}

data class StringRequest(
    override val id: Int, 
    override val value: String
) : Request<String>

data class Count(val count: String, val option: String)
data class CountRequest(
    override val id: Int, 
    override val value: Count
) : Request<Count>

data class Address(val address: String, val next: String)
data class AddressRequest(
    override val id: Int, 
    override val value: Address
) : Request<Address>
```

Actually, if you don't need the `sealed`-restriction, you don't really need the other `Request`-classes either. In that case, you could just do this:

```kotlin
data class Request<T>(val id: Int, val value: T)

val aStringRequest = Request(5, "string")

data class Count(val count: String, val option: String)
val aCountRequest = Request(5, Count("count", "option"))

data class Address(val address: String, val next: String)
val anAddressRequest = Request(5, Address("address", "next"))
```

Edit after comment from OP:

If you want only the value to be a sealed type, then you cannot support the case where the value is a string, because you cannot make `String` extend your own custom interface. If you drop that case, you can do this:

```kotlin
data class Request(val key: String, val value: RequestValue)

sealed interface RequestValue
data class Count(val count: String, val option: String) : RequestValue
data class Address(val address: String, val next: String) : RequestValue
```

Comment: I guess the `Request` subclasses would be needed if the goal was to deserialize JSONs from network responses

Comment: Probably the `sealed` modifier would be needed too if OP doesn't want to jump through hoops to define polymorphic deserialization. At least in `kotlinx.serialization` the `sealed` modifier might be sufficient IIRC, but without `sealed` the subclasses would have to be registered by hand (or explicitly mentioned on the deserialization call site, but that's not always possible)

Comment: I want to make one DTO class 
```
data class RequestDto (
  val key: String,
  val value: CommonClass
)
```
but sealed can be instantiate..  is it possible to group to CommonClass?

Comment: I updated question anyone help?

Comment: @ReallyJoey That is impossible because of the first example where the value is just a string. You cannot change the superclass of `String` to be `CommonClass`.

Comment: @marstran What If String is Ignored? I mean only Count and Address exist

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a sealed class with existing primitive types at the moment. This would call for a union type, but they are currently not denotable in Kotlin (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13108/Denotable-union-and-intersection-types).

In your case, it looks like the possible types for `value` are unrelated and don't really belong together. In that case, the best is probably to use the generics-based approach [suggested by @marstran above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75508797/1540818). This is useful and works well if you already know the `Request` subtype you need at the call site.

Another approach, at least using Kotlinx Serialization, would be to define the type as `JsonElement`, and then defer the deserialization to later (if you only know the request body type later).

Now, if the `value` property represented something specific that can have different forms (as opposed to being generic and representing any unrelated type of request body), you could define your own sealed class for that type in Kotlin (with probably a wrapper for the string version, or something better), and then add a custom JSON deserializer for your type that can deal with simple strings too.